# Is it possible to select the text from flipview in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

i have not getting selection text in WinRT so please help me. In my app i am using flipview but i have not getting copy text and selection text.

Answer (score 2):

By default `TextBlock` doesn't provide text selection. You can use read only `TextBox` to show the text which can be selected.